# x86 Assembly add and shift

Tags: assembly

How do we write an code to multiply two 32 bit integers only using shift and add. I know how to do it with 16 bit integers but how can we do it for 32 bit integers, do we need two registers to hold the upper half and bottom half?

Comment: It would be nice if you specify more details. Whether if you are on MIPS, x86, i386, or arm. Whether if you are OK with work around.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you are on i386 or above, just use eax,ebx,ecx,edx instead of ax,bx,cx,dx register.
you can use eax even if you are in real mode(16 bit).

If you want some code, here it is.
It uses other instructions like mov, and rol too tough.
(I didn't tested it.)

Multiply eax, ebx and save 32bit result to edx:

```
mov ecx, 32
xor edx, edx
next_binary_digit:
shl edx, 1
rol ebx, 1
text ebx, 1
jz add_done
add edx, eax
add_done:
loop next_binary_digit
```

If you want to use memory, it would be more complex because you may need to load value into register and shift, check carry, save back to memory.

Or.. do you want to stick to register size X yet want to multiply integer bigger than X?